# How to rewrite using .htacess when there is a ? (question mark) at the beginning of the URL?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting

Many JS functions on my site are sending Ajax request to `/?something=3213214` but I need to redirect them to `/something=3213214`

When I do:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /$1 [R]
```

It does redirect `/test/something=3213214` to `/something=3213214`

But when I do:

```
# this probably works and redirect to the same
RewriteRule ^?(.*) /$1 [R]
#OR
RewriteRule ^\?(.*) /$1 [R]
#OR
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R]
#OR
RewriteRule ^/\?(.*) /$1 [R]
```

It does not redirect to `/something=3213214`

What is the right syntaxt for this kind of redirection?

Answer (score 2):

> **Many JS functions on my site are sending Ajax request** to `/?something=3213214` but I need to redirect them to `/something=3213214`

In this case, you should really "fix" these AJAX requests. If that is not possible then you could perhaps implement a *workaround* as an *internal rewrite* - but that will depend on how the AJAX request is being routed.

Trying to *externally* "redirect" *many* such requests could cripple your site!? It may not even work, depending on how the AJAX request is implemented (it needs to expect a 3xx response and resend the request to the redirected URL).

With a request like `/?something=3213214`, everything after the first `?` is the *query string* part of the URL. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. To match the query string you need to use a `RewriteCond` (condition) directive that matches against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

> 1. `RewriteRule ^?(.*) /$1 [R]`
> 2. `RewriteRule ^\?(.*) /$1 [R]`
> 3. `RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R]`
> 4. `RewriteRule ^/\?(.*) /$1 [R]`

`#1` and `#2` would only match if the `?` was URL encoded (`%3F`) in the URL. ie. It is part of the URL-path. Additionally, `#3` and `#4` would never match in a *directory* (`.htaccess`) context because of the slash prefix

To *rewrite* such a request you would need to do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1 [QSD,L]
```

However, this is very generic, as it matches *any* query string (as your question implies) and rewrites the request accordingly. You should be as specific as possible.

`%1` (as opposed to `$1`) is a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*.

But, as mentioned, whether this works at all will be dependent on the rest of your application... how your application routes these requests (and what other directives you have).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and for time You take to help. I've noticed some of your suggestions. But still no luck. I just can't get rid of `?` from query string. I'm using PrestaShop. It's used to use `/?` as a begin of url for ajax requests, but for some weird reason it stops. But it does works with no `?`, thats why I want to rewrite links.

Comment: And these AJAX requests are 3rd party requests to PrestaShop? Has something been updated? I don't know PrestaShop I'm afraid, but I would think there would be an option to determine the URL format that it accepts, such as "query string", "path-info" or "request-uri". `/?something=3213214` is very different to `/something=3213214` - it's not simply the absence of the `?`. The way the application must read the request is potentially very different. (Many frameworks do have an option like this, to determine how such URLs are routed.)

Comment: Yes, those are 3rd party functions. To be honest, it had happened after installation of one module (I suppose), but it did not change after uninstall and remove of it.

Comment: Man,you are life saviour,BIG upvote for rewriting starting question mark.